# How to get rid of punctuation within a file using Python?

Tags: python, file

```
def main():
   key = []

   mess=input('Write Text: ')

   for ch in mess:
       x = ord(ch)
       x = x-3
       x = chr(x)
       key.append(x)

   print("Your code message is: ", "".join(key))

   outFile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","w")
   print(key, file=outFile)

main()
```

So I have written this. It gets rid of the punctuation within the Python shell but when you get read open the file something like this still looks like this `['q', 'e', 'b']` instead of this `qeb`. How would I be able to get rid of the punctuation within the file I make as well as the Python shell.

Comment: Why don't you have `coded_message = "".join(key)` and then `print("Your code message is: ", coded_message)`, end with `print(coded_message, file=outFile)`?

Answer (score 0):

key is an array and not a string
you should simply print it as a string 
like

```
   outFile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","w")
   print("".join(key), file=outFile)
```